# modify buddpress adminbar only in admin pages

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin, buddypress, api

I have modified the buddpress admin bar by creating the following plugin which adds a simple text link to the bar:

```
function bp_adminbar_currentsite_menu() {

global $bp;
?>
<li>
<!-- Insert your link url or relative url, and your link text below -->
<a href="http://EXAMPLE.COM">EXAMPLE LINK TEXT</a>
</li>
<?php
}
// Call The Function Above
add_action('bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_currentsite_menu', 999);
```

However, I do NOT want the above link to be shown when logged into the wordpress admin backend (so for example when an admin is editing a post). I thought about just doing a `php_self` check to see if it contained "/wp-admin/" but figured that there has to be a more elegant wordpress/buddypress hook here.

How can I get the above code to only show when you are viewing a normal blog page, NOT in the admin area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use the [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) `is_admin()` to check if you are on the front-end or back-end like this:

```
function bp_adminbar_currentsite_menu() {
    global $bp;
    if (!is_admin()){
        ?>
        <li>
        <!-- Insert your link url or relative url, and your link text below -->
        <a href="http://EXAMPLE.COM">EXAMPLE LINK TEXT</a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
// Call The Function Above
add_action('bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_currentsite_menu', 999);
```

Comment: thanks, is_admin() is exactly what I was looking for. I added the if statement to the "add_action" instead, just FYI, thanks again. I also asked the same question on SO here if you want to copy and paste your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461330/modify-buddpress-adminbar-only-in-admin-pages